# test-result-codecoverage.json with more than 10k coverage items

Tags: code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli, apextestrunresult

We have high number of test methods. After running all test cases using

sfdx force:apex:test:run

test-result-codecoverage.json doesn't include all classes, it includes only 25% of classes. Is there a way to include coverage from all classes as returned by

SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name,NumLinesCovered,NumLinesUncovered, Coverage FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate

When we looked into test-result-{{testId}}.json, it only include 10000 items in coverage.records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Salesforce team has identified this as an issue with SFDX CLI from version 7.159 onwards.

A [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002wJ5G) has been created with bug #W-11622957 .

> **Summary**
> Salesforce CLI version 7.159 included a version bump of the
> apex-node library from v0.13 --> v1.1.  In version 1.1, the apex-node
> library was upgraded to use more recent versions of salesforce/core
> and jsforce. The upgrading of core and jsforce seem to have impacted
> the way the maxQueryLimit is applied when retrieving test report
> results. Before cli version 7.159, increasing the maxQueryLimit to
> 1600000 (something higher than the 10k default value) would return all
> of the covered classes in the coverage report. After 7.159, increasing
> the maxQueryLimit has no effect, and a test run of many hundreds of
> files that would produce a coverage file nearing 1M lines instead
> produces a truncated coverage file that omits some of the covered
> classes.

Workaround suggested in the known issue is to

> Use a older version of SFDX CLI to run the command "sfdx force:apex:test:run" (any version prior to 7.159)

Reported on Github [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-apex/issues/303)